# How to add "Open in Safari" to Chrome right-click menu?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, automation, services

When I'm in Chrome, I'd like to be able to right-click on some links and choose "Open in Safari" from the Services submenu.

As a security precaution, how can this be done without relying on any Chrome extensions or 3rd party apps?

Comment: Have you tried making a quick action in Automator to display webpages in Safari when selecting a URL?

Comment: @ErniePC12 I've tried but it doesn't work. I can get it to display the my custom quick action "Open in Safari", but only with selected text. I don't know how to get it to extract the href when right-clicking on a link. Do you have any idea how to do this?